# Building a HTML Table Row in MVC4 Razor using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a need to add rows to a html table after a successful ajax post. This happens inside of a Modal Popup window which the javascript appends a new line to the parent screens table. The appending is working with the exception of I do not see how to take a field value from the modal and use it as a variable in the javascript .append statement. Below is the current success method for the ajax call which works correctly except for not getting the NoteText value.

```
success: function (result) {
                var noteText = $("#NoteText").val();
                $("#TenantNotesTable").append('<tr><td class="EditButton">@Html.ActionLink("Note Details", "AddTenantNote", New With {.id = 0}, New With {.id = "openDialog", .class = "ButtonControl"})</td><td class="NoteDate">@DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString</td><td class="noteText">NoteText SHOULD SHOW HERE</td><td class="EnterBy">@Model.NoteEnteredBy</td>');
                $('#waitMessage').hide();
                $("#dialog-edit").dialog().dialog('close');

            },
```

Please excuse this question as I am learning Javascript on a as needed basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the correct way to fix it I needed to add `'+noteText+'` in the append statement in the correct location.